# Can a photon in a optic fiber interfere with itself destructively?

Tags: photons, double-slit-experiment, interference, fiber-optics

In Young double slit experiment the photons interfere with themselves destructively and constructively. So when there is an optic fiber with a mirror end the photon should return back and one can calculate the length of the fiber in order the incoming and the reflected photons wavefunctions are over imposed so it vanishes. Is that possible and if not, why?

Comment: You might want to consider how a DBR (distributed Bragg reflector) works.

Comment: Ok thanks i ll do

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. In fact, using a fiber is an unnecessary complication: one can send a photon at a mirror, it will reflect itself and form a self-interference pattern in space.

A commonly considered situation where such a thing happens is Fabri-Perot resonator, consisting of two mirrors, where a standing wave with maxima and zeros/nodes forms. If one wishes to couple such a resonator to an emitter/receiver of radiation, one has to place the antenna in the maximum of the standing wave, since placing it in the minimum will result in absence of coupling. The same principles govern optical fibers, although with complications due to the dielectric (note that a mirror is just a piece of metal).

Comment: No, I dont mean nodes but an incoming and back travelling after reflection waves which extinguish themselves completely. I realize that this a box with dimensions that are not proper for the photon to enter.

Comment: Essentially, the question is whether a propagating mode may become non-propagating using only a mirror.

Comment: Or can we put a mirror at the end of a optic fiber and stop propagation. Something similar which @PhysicsDave is describing in his answer?

Answer (score 1):

Interference is a classical method for explaining the experiment. You can also use the Feynman approach ... only certain paths (modes) are allowed for a photon, they must travel a distance/path n times the wavelength (n is integer).  For example if your source is a laser diode you can set an external mirror so no photons are created .... you can verify this as the laser diode current varies with the mirror distance.

Comment: This is very intriguing. I like to see a plot. Where is your source from? Are there not constructive paths nearby or the diod is unidirectional? Does the current go to zero?

Comment: Any laser can be upset by misalignment of the internal mirrors or even external mirrors.  Yes a laser diode (like a cheap laser pointer) is unidirectional because of the attached collimating lens.  No the current does not quite go to zero for a laser diode because it goes into LED like mode when the paths are upset .... it is possible to damage the LD as well.  The most important concept is that photons do not really "interfere" if we think of it as energy cancelling ... that is a violation of conservation of energy.  So the better explanation (IMO) is using Feynman paths.

Comment: Why should the LD damage? As I understand it will not emit at all.

Comment: @PhysicsDave...Photons, mmm? (EM waves) do interfere with  themselves, but destructive interference is misleading, energy is never destroyed but transformed from E field to H field. E and H are 90 deg out of phase when standing. Standing wave can be probed, when E is zero, current can be measured at that node to be maximum.